# How do I prove the following maps are completely positive?

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-operation, trace-distance

I am trying to prove that the following superoperators are quantum channels, that is completely positive and trace-perserving linear maps

1 $\Psi[M]=WMW^\dagger$ where $W$ is an isometry

2 $\Psi[M_A]=M_A\otimes\sigma_B$ where $\sigma_B$ is a state

3 partial trace: $\Psi[M_{AB}]=Tr_B[M_{AB}]$

4 $\Psi[M]=\sum_{x,y}p(y|x)<x|M|x>|y><y|$ with $p(y|x)$ a conditional probability distribution

**I have already verified the trace-preserving property but I have no idea how to deal with the completely positive definition . How does one do that?**

My defintion is:

Definition: A superoperator $\Phi$ in $L(L(H_A),L(H_B)) $is completely positive if $(\Phi \otimes \mathcal{I}_R)(M_A) \geq 0$ is true for all  $\mathcal{H}_R$, given that $M_A\geq0\,.$

Comment: Check the relevant properties of the Choi matrix or show it has a Kraus form, then you know it is a quantum channel.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method is the apply your superoperator to one half of a maximally entangled state on $\mathbb{C}^d\otimes\mathbb{C}^d$ (as a density matrix) where your operator takes inputs from the space $\mathbb{C}^d$. The outcome is a state called the Choi map. Its eigenvalues are non-negative if and only if the superoperator is completely positive.

Take case (2) as an example. if $|B\rangle$ is your Bell state, then
$$
I\otimes\Psi(|B\rangle\langle B|)=|B\rangle\langle B| \otimes \sigma_B.
$$
This is clearly a valid density matrix, so the eigenvalues are all between 0 and 1. Hence, the operation is completely positive.

Comment: Could you show (2) as an example?

Comment: Shoudn't it be "Choi state" rather than "Choi map"?

Comment: Possibly. I certainly concede it's not a map. But it also might not be a state...